# How to make powers work right on a casio calculator?

Tags: exponentiation, calculator

I pressed some random buttons and it worked fine,but now its not working again. for example my calculator shows that -6^2 is - 36 and not 36, anyone know how to fix it???

My clculator model is casio fx-83gt plus

Comment: Operator precedence, `-6^2` is $-(6^2)$, not $(-6)^2$.

Comment: You need to type $(-6)^2$.  It's doing order of operations, treating the "-" like $(-1) \cdot 6^2$.